# How to get a remote video file's size in bytes with javascript

Tags: javascript, http, dom, html5-video

I want to determine the file size of a remote video, e.g. `http://example.com/video.mp4`. **I CAN NOT DO IT WITH AJAX** because the browser's CORS restriction, also can't manipulate the video host server.

There are my attempts (not succeed):

1. I added an invisible `<video>` tag and its `src` will be assigned programmatically. The browser fires a http request when the `src` is assigned. I can see the request and corresponding response in chrome developer tools' `Network` tab. I'm wondering is there a way to get those information in my code. Once I get the response header, I can simply extract the file size from `Content-Length` field of the header.
2. I thought of the `progress` event of the `video` DOM, but there is no properties like `total`, 'loaded` for the event object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your real question is how to get the size of the video (in bytes), that should be your question, not "How to get HTTP response header in javascript". That's just how you think you have to do it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry for that, I've edited the question and question body.